# Solemness OR Solemnity

Tags: nouns

1. He was smiling, but his eyes retained a look of solemness/solemnity.

Which one is correct here? Here we need a noun, but both solemness and solemnity are noun. So I am confused which one to use here.

Comment: This seems another case where English speakers couldn't decide which suffix to use, so they picked both.  As far as I know, these words have the same meaning, so it's entirely a question of which *sounds* better to you.  Personally, I prefer "solemnity" but someone else might have an entirely different opinion.

Comment: solemnity is best.

Comment: Solemnity is an import from Latin solemnitas. It would also be used as a noun to mean "important feast"

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=solemness%2C+solemnity&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csolemness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csolemnity%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both mean the same thing - a trait of dignified seriousness.

We mostly use "solemnity", whereas we hardly ever use the  "solemness/solemnness". Even we don't find the solemness/solemnness in most dictionaries.